# Is there a hotkey to set bevel weight?

Tags: bevel

Is there a keyboard shortcut I can use to set the edge bevel weight?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can add a shortcut in Edit Mode using the bar at the bottom of the 3D view.

The button in the menu for Edge Bevel Weight is under `Mesh ‣ Edges ‣ Edge Bevel Weight`.
[image: Edge Bevel Weight menu location]

Right-click the button and then select `Add shortcut` from the popup menu that appears. You can also do this with any other item in the menu or the toolbar on the left.
[image: Adding a shortcut]

Also notice that the shortcut for the Edges menu is `Ctrl E`, so if you wanted you could type `Ctrl E` in the 3D view and select `Edge Bevel Weight`. You can also add a shortcut from this menu by right clicking and selecting 'Add Shortcut', as above.
[image: Using the 'shortcut']